# Why is this WHERE clause not working with Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite new to SQL and this is rather a complex command :

```
SELECT users.name, 
       from_unixtime(activity.time_stamp, "%D %b %Y  %l:%i:%S"), 
      activity.activity, 
      activity.rfid_tag, 
      chemicals.description 
FROM activity 
JOIN chemicals ON chemicals.bar_code = activity.bar_code 
JOIN users ON users.badge_number=activity.badge_number 
WHERE  (activity="login") 
    OR (activity="logout") 
   OR (activity LIKE "Admin:%") 
   OR (activity="tag") 
   OR (activity="untag") 
   OR (activity LIKE "check out%") 
   OR (activity LIKE "pour%") 
   OR (activity="check out (unscheduled)") 
   OR (activity="not poured after checking out") 
   OR (activity LIKE "invalid:%") 
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```

When I run it, it returns *only* the rows which match the last OR of the WHERE (723 from 867). For instance, I do not see any rows where activity="login", but `SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity="login"` does return some rows.

What am I doing wrong? (and if that should be "INNER JOIN")?

### Update

I should have said this was working (with the complex WHERE) before I added the Join (and I am a total SQL beginner).

Comment: `activity` is the name of table, as well as column, o_0

Comment: Ok but you are adding the conditions as well where `activity="login"` and `chemicals.bar_code = activity.bar_code` and `users.badge_number=activity.badge_number` is that condition still true?

Comment: are `bar_code` and `badge_number` nullable fields? If so, then perhaps the joins on `chemicals` and/or `users` should be `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: if you change the order of your `OR`s, do you still get the last OR, or the `OR (activity LIKE "invalid:%")`

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS why would mysql match a value against a table name?

Comment: this likely won't change anything but have you tried removing all of the parentheses? I don't think they're needed

Comment: +1 @AdrianCornish  I know that you are writing english saying that I am adding 'activity="login" and chemicals.bar_code = activity.bar_code" when they are actually OR. If any one of them is true, I want to see that row (with the joins). It worked before I added the Joins (and see the question "SELECT * FROM activity WHERE activity="login" does return some rows"). Can you help? thanks

Comment: +1 @hobbs yes, some fields cans be null (bar_code and rfid_tag)

Comment: +1 @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS  Surely there is notjing wrong with having field and tale name the same? In a table called activity, the most import field is the activity. It's syntactically ok (isn't it?)

Comment: @Mawg Read my comment again that was not directed at you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please study the difference between [INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN](http://www.quora.com/SQL/What-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).

From looking at your query and crystal ball-gazing based on the names and correlating to real world entities, here's what I can see:

When your activity is "pour", it may involve some chemical, which will join successfully on barcode.  When it is "login", I doubt you'll get a successful (INNER) JOIN against the chemical table.  As someone has mentioned, you really want to turn them into LEFT JOINs, e.g.

```
SELECT users.name, 
       from_unixtime(activity.time_stamp, "%D %b %Y  %l:%i:%S"), 
      activity.activity, 
      activity.rfid_tag, 
      chemicals.description 
FROM activity 
LEFT JOIN chemicals ON chemicals.bar_code = activity.bar_code 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.badge_number=activity.badge_number 
WHERE  (activity="login") 
   OR (activity="logout") 
   OR (activity LIKE "Admin:%") 
   OR (activity="tag") 
   OR (activity="untag") 
   OR (activity LIKE "check out%") 
   OR (activity LIKE "pour%") 
   OR (activity="check out (unscheduled)") 
   OR (activity="not poured after checking out") 
   OR (activity LIKE "invalid:%") 
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
```